# How can i symlink home directory in linux

Tags: linux, redhat, home-directory

I have my home directory in /home/tom.
In another partition I have a folder called /data/tomhome.

Basically, I copy all of my data from /data/tomhome to /home/tom

But whenever I update files in /data/tomhome, I still have to copy them to the other directory.

Another way will be to symlink all files but i don't want to make 20 symlinks.

Is there any other way for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
ln -s /home/tom /data/tomhome
```

**Note**: You should delete the directory `/data/tomhome` with `rm -rf /data/tomhome` if it exists already

Comment: That directory is already there and i can't delete it. That drive is the another disk which i mount

Comment: @Karl You may create the symlink in the `/data/tomhome/something` and it would be interpreted as a subdirectory.